# Debugging C programs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug a C program using Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu.

I set

> "program": "${workspaceRoot}/sample"

in the launch.json where "sample" is the name of my program. Then I simply put a breakpoint in code and click the debug arrow. However, the debugger does not hit the breakpoint, a terminal simply flashes and closes.
When I hover over my breakpoint it says:

> Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint
>   adress could not be obtained.

Is there an additional setting that I must configure ?

Comment: There was a similar issue posted [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40202778-can-t-stop-at-the-breakpoint) which contains a solution. Does that work for you?

Comment: Ah thank you. I was missing the -g tag when compiling.

Comment: @SpiderRico, If this issue has been resolved, you could add the solution as the answer and mark it. So it would help other community members who meet the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with VS code. I was simply missing the -g tag when compiling the program.

Comment: Thanks! landed here after 1hr of searching everywhere!